# Exchange get Active Mailboxes with last activity not older than

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Hi i tried to perform a script in exchange (and exchange online) to find shared mailboxes as on topic

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox | Where {(Get-MailboxStatistics $_.Id
entity).LastLogonTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)} | Sort -Property @{e={( Get-MailboxStatistics $_.Identity).LastLogonTime}} -Descending | Select-Object DisplayName,@{n="LastLogonTime";e={(Get-Mailbo
xStatistics $_.Identity).LastLogonTime}}|Where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*.uk*")}
```

I got an error

> Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing.
>   Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [],
>   PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePipelineExecutionFailed

I am unable to identity an error ... can you please help ?

I used below sources

http://www.thatlazyadmin.com/get-exchange-active-mailboxes/

https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/list-of-active-mailboxes-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

I have rearranged the parts of your query to make it work.

```
$Output = Foreach ($mailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox |
    Where-Object {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*.uk*"})) {
        $stats = $null
        $stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $mailbox.UserPrincipalName |
            Where-Object {$_.LastLogonTime -gt (Get-Date).Adddays(-60)}
        $stats | Sort-Object LastLogonTime -Descending |
            Select-Object DisplayName,LastLogonTime
}
$Output # Outputs to the console
```

This should be faster simply because it reduces the number of times you have run `Get-MailboxStatistics`. `$Output` stores the final query results, which you can access by just typing the variable name. Outputting as each object is processed (unlike what we are doing here) is painfully slow.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks ! Will this show user who logged for last 60 days ?

Comment: Yes. The second `Where-Object` contains that condition.